# CSRF, javascript and jquery

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

Is it possible for a CSRF attack to read the contents of global JavaScript variables already present on the victim's browser?

My plan is to have the application store a CSRFToken value that is stored in the session when the user successfully logs on, and then I save that in a globally accessible JavaScript variable for use in the application.  I will use jQuery to automatically append this value to any form post action within the application. On the server side I will check to see if the values match and either complete the action or block it if no match is found.

My understanding is that a CSRF attack can be deployed by a variety of methods, but they all need to re-direct the victim to a 3rd party site to execute malicious code.  The 3rd party site can try to forge a form request for example, but unless they know the contents of the CSRFToken, the action will fail.   Unless of course.. they can get to it somehow.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but this seems like a bad idea. Hopefully someone will correct me.

Comment: I found the original idea here: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118

Answer (score 0):

[CSRF attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) by definition does not need any data from your browser to be visible on 3rd party site (i.e. attacker). As a result, CSRF attack does not (or cannot) read any state within the browser (cookies or javascript variables).